# Difference between Instruments (Zombies and leaks)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management, nszombie

I'm now managing the 'memory' of my new app', but i found a difference that i don't understand. Look at this pic :

[image: Difference]

The allocations curves are not similar at all. It's from Zombie mode, and Leaks analyzer. But why is it different because the curves seems to be from allocation ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not pay any attention to your memory usage curves with Zombies enabled. With Zombies enabled, memory for Objective-C objects is never freed. (That's how zombies work: instead of deallocating the object, the runtime replaces the dead object with a zombie object that complains if it is ever used.)